# Fill up DataFrame counting to full cartesian product

Tags: python, pandas, count, cartesian-product

Look at this code:

```
result=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].count())
```

It basically does what I want to with one minor issue: I want the result to have the full cartesian product of all occurring values of col1 and col2 as index. Of course, my command takes only those combinations of col1 and col2 into account which actually are present in `df`. I'd like to fill up the result with 0 entries at the non occuring elements of the cartesian product. How do I do that?

**Example:** Let's say `df` contians the values

- `('A',1,'Bob')`
- `('A',1,'James')`
- `('A',2,'Bond')`
- `('B',3,'Alice')`
- `('C',1,'Klaus')`
- `('C',1,'Peter')`

Then the result is

- `('A',1)` : 2
- `('A',2)` : 1
- `('B',3)` : 1
- `('C',1)` : 2

I want it to be filled up with

- `('A',3)` : 0
- `('B',1)` : 0
- `('B',2)` : 0
- `('C',2)` : 0
- `('C',3)` : 0

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframe(s) and expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Paul I added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

```
result = df.groupby(["col1", "col2"])["col3"].count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```

result :

```
col1  col2
A     1       2
      2       1
      3       0
B     1       0
      2       0
      3       1
C     1       2
      2       0
      3       0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's great! I have one follow up question. Let's say I keep the DataFrame at `df.groupby(["col1", "col2"])["col3"].count().unstack(fill_value=0)` without restacking. How do I get rid of my main column and make the three columns of second order to first order columns?

Comment: can you show me an example of what you wany?